# Integrating delta function with a one-sided function

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

Suppose I have a real function $f(x)$ that is only non-zero for $x \geq 0$. Is the integral $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\delta(x)f(x)dx$ defined?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/integrate-product-of-dirac-delta-and-discontinuous-function

Comment: Thanks! A relevant question: is the integral still defined if the delta function is replaced with the Dirac unit doublet $\delta'(x)$?