# Can we integrate the dirac delta of an a.e. discontinuous function?

Tags: integration, continuity, dirac-delta

Let's say I have a real valued function $f$ and a subset $S \subset \mathbb{R}$. Let's also define the dirac measure to be
$
\delta_{x}(S) =  \begin{cases}
        1 & x \in S \\
        0 & x \not\in S
    \end{cases}$

I would expect the following to be true:

$\int_{x' \in \mathbb{R}}
      \int_{z \in S}
      d\delta_{f(x')}(z) \  d\delta_{0}(x') = \begin{cases}
        1 & f(0) \in S \\
        0 & f(0) \not\in S
    \end{cases}$

Is this always the case? Does this hold if $f$ is discontinuous almost everywhere?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/integrate-product-of-dirac-delta-and-discontinuous-function

Comment: Do you the definition of integration? If so, your question is trivial... By definition, $\int_{z \in S}d\delta_{f(x')}(z) = 1_{f(x') \in S}$, so your double integral is $\int_{x' \in \mathbb{R}} 1_{f(x') \in S}d\delta_0(x') = 1_{f(0) \in S}$.

Comment: @mathworker21 I am not entirely sure I understand. I am using Lebesgue integration and defining the Dirac measure explicitly here

Comment: @gigalord I hope you don't mean "integrating with respect to Lebesgue measure" when you say "Lebesgue integration". You are integrating with respect to an abstract measure (which is defined as supremum of 'integral' of step functions less than function you are integrating). Also, I wish you would say what you didn't understand. Do you not understand $\int_{z \in S} d\delta_{f(x')}(z) = 1_{f(x') \in S}$?

Comment: Hi @mathworker21, here is what I do not understand: is it the case that if we define the measure $g_{x}$ such that  $
g_{x}(S) =  \begin{cases}
        1 & x \in S \\
        0 & x \not\in S
    \end{cases}$ then is it always the case that  $\int_{z \in S} dg_{f(x')}(z)  = 1_{f(x') \in S}$, regardless of the properties of $f$?

Comment: @gigalord $f(x')$ is just a point, so $f$ as a whole doesn't maatter